# unable to post to AXL endpoint

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, cisco, cisco-axl

My goal is to be able to post and retrieve from the endpoint which uses a SOAP based API

---

**structure of my project**

I generated a client with the WSDL file to target cucm 11.5, then

I followed the example on [github](https://github.com/jonasbutt/AXL.NET/tree/master/Client) by creating all the classes and interfaces as done on the repo

thirdly, my solution consist of two project a class library and a console project, the class library contains the generated client from the WSDL file and the console project consist of the class and interfaces to interact with the class library project

---

> I have the following class to perform an operation

---

```
 public class TestAxl
{

    public void CreateUsers()
    {
        var axlClient = new AxlClient(new AxlClientConfiguration
        {
            Server = "Ip to the publish server",

            User = "administrator",
            Password = "password provided"


        });




        var addUserResult = axlClient.ExecuteAsync(async client =>
       {
           var userId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
           var request = new AddUserReq
           {
               user = new XUser
               {
                   userid = userId,
                   userIdentity = userId,
                   password = "P@ssw0rd",
                   firstName = "test",
                   lastName = "test"
               }
           };
           var response = await client.addUserAsync(request);
           return response.addUserResponse1.@return;
       });



    }



}
```

> and i call it from the main class like so

---

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {



        var letsDoSomeTesting = new TestAxl();

        try
        {
             letsDoSomeTesting.CreateUsers();



        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {



            Console.WriteLine("The following is the exceeption from calling final class ", e.Message);

        }





    }



}
```

---

### when i try to run the console project it starts and exit with 0,

then i go back to CUCM sandbox environment and nothing has changed, what could be the possible cause of this operation not working

FYI: Runtime netCore 3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get a sample project together including AXL/addUser, with DotNet Core 3.1 on Linux: https://github.com/CiscoDevNet/axl-dotnet-samples

This is the main section:

```
// Create a custom binding so we can allow the client to use cookies with AXL
BasicHttpsBinding binding = new BasicHttpsBinding();
binding.AllowCookies = true;

// Specify the CUCM AXL API location for the SOAP client
EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress( $"https://{ System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable( "CUCM_ADDRESS" ) }:8443/axl/" );

//Class generated from AXL WSDL
AXLPortClient client = new AXLPortClient( binding, address );

// To disable HTTPS certificate checking, uncomment the below lines
// NOT for production use!

// client.ChannelFactory.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SslCertificateAuthentication = new X509ServiceCertificateAuthentication
//     {
//         CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None,
//         RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck
//     };
// client.ChannelFactory.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None;
// client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None;

// Incantation to force alternate serializer reflection behaviour due to complexities in the AXL schema
// See https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/2219
MethodInfo method = typeof( XmlSerializer ).GetMethod( "set_Mode", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static );
method.Invoke( null, new object[] { 1 } ); 

// Base64 encode AXL username/password for Basic Auth
var encodedUserPass = Convert.ToBase64String( Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes( 
    System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable( "CUCM_USERNAME" ) + ":" +
    System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable( "CUCM_PASSWORD" )
) );

// Incantation to create and populate a Basic Auth HTTP header
// This must be done to force SoapCore to include the Authorization header on the first attempt
// rather than in challenge/response fashion
HttpRequestMessageProperty requestProperty = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
requestProperty.Headers[ "Authorization" ] = "Basic " + encodedUserPass;

// Creating context block apparently allows attaching custom HTTP headers to the request
var scope = new OperationContextScope( client.InnerChannel );
OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[ HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name ] = requestProperty;

//Create the request object
AddUserReq addUserReq = new AddUserReq(); 

addUserReq.user = new XUser();
addUserReq.user.lastName = "TestUser";
addUserReq.user.userid = "testUser";
addUserReq.user.password = "Cisco!1234";

string userPkid = "";

//Try the addUser request
try
    {
        addUserResponse addUserResp = await client.addUserAsync( addUserReq );
        userPkid = addUserResp.addUserResponse1.@return;
    }
catch ( Exception ex )
    {
        Console.WriteLine( $"\nError: addUser: { ex.Message }" );
        Environment.Exit( -1 );
    }
```

A few notes:

- SoapCore generates elements with default values when it can, e.g. nil for string elements.  This causes a problem with `<addUser>`, as the `<customerName>` element should only be sent to [HCS CUCMs](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/unified-communications/hosted-unified-communications-services/index.html).  A modification to the AXLSoap.xsd before running svcutil was able to workaround it:

  ```
  sed -i 's/name=\"customerName\" nillable=\"true\"/name=\"customerName\" nillable=\"false\"/g' schema/AXLSoap.xsd
  ```
- Requests will fail due to HTTPS certification validation of the CUCM self-signed certificate, unless it is installed to the OS CA trust store or disabled (see the commented section in the code above)
- The following curious code was required to avoid a "Compiling JScript/CSharp scripts is not supported" error on making a request (per [here](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/2219)):

  ```
  MethodInfo method = typeof( XmlSerializer ).GetMethod( "set_Mode", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static );
  method.Invoke( null, new object[] { 1 } );
  ```